# Android WorkManager: How to handle a growing number of worker with constraint?

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

Currently, we have setup sending email worker, with Internet is available constraint.

```
// Create a Constraints that defines when the task should run
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        // Many other constraints are available, see the
        // Constraints.Builder reference
        .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
        new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(EmailWorker.class)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, EMAIL_WORKER_BACKOFF_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addTag(EmailWorker.TAG)
                .setInputData(inputData)
                .build();

WorkManager workManager = getWorkManager();
workManager.enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
```

We was wondering. What if, the Internet is never available for long period?

1. Can we specific maximum number of allowable pending worker based on selected TAG? (To avoid out of memory/ out of disk space)
2. When the maximum number of allowable pending worker is reached, can we discard the oldest worker, and accept the newest worker?

Comment: Do you need more than one `EmailWorker`? If not, perhaps the "unique work" feature is the right one to use.

Comment: Yes. We allow user to send "unlimited" email. Any failure of email delivery API call, we will have N retry for that. When previous email is still pending, we still allow user to keep sending.

Comment: But, why do you need multiple workers for that? When the worker becomes active, send all queued messages.

Comment: We want to avoid complication of designing our own queue system. We want to utilize existing WorkManager framework, to keep thing simple.

Comment: FWIW, [Tape](https://github.com/square/tape) is a queue system.

Comment: I think I will give a thought over that. Introducing a new component also mean open door for new bugs.